# What is the purpose of Rb in the 3rd step of the 3-pass mutual authentication in ISO/IES 9798-2?

Tags: authentication, mutual

Recently I am studying ISO 9798-2 Three-pass mutual authentication. There are 3 steps, as following:

1. `B -> A: NB` // B sends to A a "nonce" value `NB`
2. `A -> B: {NB||NA}K` // A's identity is proven to B by showing B that A has the correct pre-shared secret `K` to encrypt the challenge `NB`.
3. `B -> A: {NA||NB}K` // B authenticates itself to A by decrypting the encrypted challenge `NA`.

My question is, why bother using `NB` again in the 3rd step ? Couldn't B proves its identity by simply sending A the `NA` value ? The 3rd step could be simplified like this: "`B -> A: NA`". From some documents on the Internet, it seems to have some crypto-purpose to re-add `NB` into the 3rd step. Why ?

Comment: Just like to point out that what you described is how the `NXP DESFire 3-Pass Mutual Authentication` is implemented. That is, `NB` is not used in the third step and as you pointed out only an encrypted `NA'` is what is sent back to `A`. And to prevent an impostor that simply echoes back what it received, it shifts left `NB`, concatinate it with `NA`, encrypts the two stuff and sends it back to `B`. Then `B` with knowledge of the halves, takes out one half and decrypts it and shifts right it and does a compare, thus proving one side. The last step does the same thing, to complete the proof.

Answer (score 1):

In all generality, authentication protocols strives to be *provably* secure while assuming the minimum of properties for the used primitives. For instance, do all challenges have the same length ? When using concatenation (as in `NA || NB`), is the separation between `NA` and `NB` unambiguously defined ? To what extent is the encryption mechanism malleable (e.g. what does happen if an attacker tries to swap the two halves of an encrypted message) ? Inclusion of `NB` in the third message is an attempt at avoiding some attacks of this kind.

See [this document](http://e-collection.library.ethz.ch/eserv/eth:2872/eth-2872-01.pdf) for an analysis of the ISO 9798 authentication protocols. The three-pass protocol is actually not optimally secure.

Comment: If AES is used in this three-pass mutual authentication protocol, is it still necessary to re-encrypt NB at the third step?